# meta-tags for all pages in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

`<Helmet> <title>Best Hospital in India – Medical Tourism Company | Trusted hospitals</title> <meta name="title" content="Best Hospital in India – Medical Tourism Company | Trusted hospitals" /> <meta name="description" content="Listed with best hospitals in India, VBcuremart is your medical travel partner which works with top doctors in the best hospitals to give you quality treatment." /> </Helmet>`

I have created a CRA application, I need to update the meta tags based on the pages.

I have used react-helmet but SEO tools are unable to find the meta title and descriptions

I have implemented the helmet tag which is imported from react-helmet.
In that, I added meta title tags and description tags.

I need to update the metatags base upon the displaying page

Comment: <Helmet>
  <title>Best Hospital in India – Medical Tourism Company | Trusted hospitals</title>
  <meta name="title" content="Best Hospital in India – Medical Tourism Company | Trusted hospitals" />
  <meta name="description" content="Listed with best hospitals in India, VBcuremart is your medical travel partner which works with top doctors in the best hospitals to give you quality treatment." />
</Helmet>

Comment: Above is the code what i have tried

Comment: Please include this in your question by editing it, it will be clearer

Answer (score 0):

u can use a dep called react-document-meta check documentation from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-document-meta

Comment: thanks u so much adel. I have tried using this document meta. Even though my problem is not solved.. My app is client side rendering which is created by Create-React-App.